# nautilus opens but not displayed (Debian Jessie)

Tags: debian, gnome, nautilus

in sometimes when I open a folder `nautilus` suddenly is stopped. **(Freezes the folders and/or graphic interfaces)**

then I must restart the system for solve problem because nautilus not open.

I try:

```
killall -9 nautilus
sudo apt-get remove nautilus && sudo apt-get install nautilus
```

- I've tried delete cache, but don't work.
- Restart gdm with `service gdm restart` and `service gdm3 restart`
- Close user sessions
- **Edit:** Also I've tried clicked in "New window", appears loading but the nautilus don't shown

but when I opens the `nautilus` don't shown, only can see this:

[image: nautilus]

How could I solve it?. Thank you very much!

PD: nautilus version is: `GNOME nautilus 3.14.1`

Comment: @don_crissti I've readead about of `jounalctl`, thank you, but I would like know what option must use to show the information that you need for help me.  Thank you very much :D

Comment: Try `journalctl /usr/bin/nautilus` as a user. You can always create another user account and see if you can replicate the behaviour. If you can't then some settings on your user account are to blame.

Comment: `journalctl /usr/bin/nautilus`
*-- Logs begin at Mon 2016-05-02 09:13:48 COT, end at Mon 2016-05-02 15:17:01 COT. --* ... Don't show more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem.

the **Megasync** for linux, also I've tested the **megasync (amd64 - version 2.9.10-25.1)** in *kali linux 2.0 2016.2 light and have the same problem*

**What is the problem with megasync? Causes froozen folder of nautilus interfaces (In random times)**

Unistall megasync or kill process when have a problem

```
sudo killall -9 megasync
```

Greetings!